# What happens to a running program when my computer switches to Hibernate?

Tags: matlab

my laptop goes to hibernate when I'm running a matlab code because of overheating. when I turn it on again, matlab countinue to running my code. I'm worry about the results of my code! what do you think? is there any problem with hibernating and resuming the matlab code?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/46569-what-happens-to-a-running-program-when-my-computer-switches-to-hibernate

Theoretically, when the computer hibernates, the status of the memory and disk are saved. However, as it is pointed out in the link I provided, this is not very reliable and can lead to corruption of files and/or data.

Instead, I recommend that your program saves necessary variables from time to time using checkpoints, so that your program can run reliably even when your code is paused or your computer hibernates. Take a look at this link to see how to implement checkpoints: http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=5343.